# How can I forward an external IP to multiple local servers?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, wireless, router

I am developing an iPhone app where I am using a local Mac as a web server. I also have another Mac which I plan to use as a backup. My question is - given that there is one URL request in the application, is it possible to route the request to either computers?

I read a lot about port forwarding but did not see a case where you can forward to multiple local web servers.

EDIT:

The selection of the server can either be random or just serial - if the first one doesnt respond, try the second one. My point here is that in case my main server gets shut off from some reason (restart for example), there will be another one to respond. I am not looking to distribute the traffic load.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you want both computers to respond? Only one of them? Which in this case? Should it be chosen randomly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have two machines on the happy side of a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) firewall / router.

I assume that you want your requests to be handled by either server *at random*.

#### Round robin DNS

One possible way you can do this is give both computers the same hostname in a DNS server (most routers provide some DNS software). If your router software lets you assign *two* IP addresses to a specific hostname (many can) *and* lets you assign a short DNS TTL, you could have your port-forwarding forward to the *hostname*, and let [round robin DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_dns) provide cheap load-balancing for you.

This relies on your DNS server randomizing the responses to round-robin DNS requests and also relies on your router to query DNS for addresses for forwarding. (Which is the weakest part of my suggestion -- forwarding to a *hostname* is definitely a funny thing to desire.)

#### Explicit port selection

Another possibility is for your router to have *three* ports configured for forwarding: forward port `80` to a script that randomly redirects (response `302`) to port `81` or port `82`. Direct port `81` to one machine, port `82` to the other machine. This will make your URLs uglier (`http://www.example.com:81/path/to/resource`) but places fewer requirements on your router.

Comment: Thanks, samold. Can you show an example of how to setup the round robin solution? any additional help would be great since I am not sure how to go about doing that. thanks!

Comment: The server I'm most familiar with, PowerDNS, provides a [pipe backend](http://doc.powerdns.com/pipebackend-dynamic-resolution.html) that was designed specifically for this sort of fast-TTL responses. Other servers may have different mechanisms available.

Comment: Ah, I just now saw your edit to the question -- what you're _really_ after is probably more like [IP failover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failover). You might be able to do it cheaply on the router if it can run arbitrary programs...